# useState for event handler without callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the code below:

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";

import React, {
  useState,
  useEffect,
  useMemo,
  useRef,
  useCallback
} from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [channel, setChannel] = useState(null);

  const handleClick1 = useCallback(() => {
    console.log(channel);
  }, [channel]);

  const handleClick2 = () => {
    console.log(channel);
  };

  const parentClick = () => {
    console.log("parent is call");
    setChannel((prev) => prev + 1);
  };
  // useEffect(() => {
  //   setChannel(1);
  // });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={parentClick}>parent click</button>
      <br />
      <br />
      <button onClick={handleClick1}>child click1</button>
      <button onClick={handleClick2}>child click2</button>
      &nbsp;
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);
root.render(<App />);
```

There is one child click wrap with callback (`handleclick1`) and one didn't  (`handleclick2`).
After parent click, both children get the right  `channel` state value.
My question is for `handleclick2` :

1. will the change of `channel` state value trigger the re-evaluation of the function and hence rerendering of the entire UI?
2. If the answer for 1 is no, then how the function got the right value of `channel` state value?

see [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-dawn-w94k49?file=/src/index.js) here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> will the change of channel state value trigger the re-evaluation of the function and hence rerendering of the entire UI?

Yes, but this isn't due to anything in `handleClick2` - it's due to the state setter being called. Whenever a state setter is called, the component will re-render - which means, in this case, that the `App` function runs again.

`useCallback` is usually useful when passing down a function to another React component as a prop, to reduce *that* component's need to re-calculate things. It's not useful in situations like these where everything is done in a single component.